# Unity 3D doesn't work on ubuntu 12.04 LTS in virtual box hosted by Windows 7 64bit

Tags: 12.04, ati, windows-7, virtualbox, 3d

Can't google out the solution through some time so I'm asking here.

I have installed Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in virtual box hosted by Windows 7 64bit

Simple >>>my 3D stopped working after some kernel headers update<<< few months ago. Just like that. I don't member which version was it.

In meantime there was 2 or 3 new releases of VirtualBox which I have installed.
Every time I am updating VirtualBox Guest Additions to the newest version.

My 3D in Ubuntu still doesn't work.

```
root@pjadmin-VirtualBox:~# /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.2
Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes 
GL fragment program:      yes   
GL vertex buffer object:  yes   
GL framebuffer object:    yes 
GL version is 1.4+:       yes
Unity 3D supported:       no
```

My graphics card in PC is ATI 6850. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys. I have solved the problem.

This are some steps I made to fix it.

- Uninstall the guest additions ( again ... )
- Restart
- After restart I went into System settings -> Additional Drivers and I enabled virtual box driver ( It starts downloading guest additions ). When I tried to install it from the VirtualBox menu ( Install guest additions ) it didnt work.
- After another restart the name of this driver has been changed into Oracle VM VirtualBox Additions for Linux Module

NOTE that when I tried to disable / enable drivers with installed guest additions system crashed ( only reset helps ) and refused to start. ... and most cofusing ... it was looking enabled.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This instructions are given for this setup:

Host 64bit system (Windows 8)
Guest 32bit system (Ubuntu 12.04.2)

After installation of ubuntu you can get a problem with low graphics mode error and that problem is resolvable with updating system from console interface

Hallo!

I think I have solution for installing Guest Additions on Ubuntu 12.04.2 that can help with some driver issues

I prefer to do all the job in terminal Ctrl+Alt+T, will launch it

Saw a lot of people saying that you have to disable 3D acceleration before launching the machine.

---

> Main thing to do on fresh install in virtualbox with ubuntu 12.04 - do all updates

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

when this will be done

```
sudo reboot
```

when system boots again do this

this will update headers

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

> Done with updates and upgrades

---

Now you need to prepare you system for installing Guest Additions

Firstly remove all preinstalled stuff from virtualbox

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox*
```

Then install essential soft for installing Guest Additions

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential
```

This step is just to check that headers are correctly installed

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Just in case reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

---

> Further, please note
>   I had to install fglrx driver here (I have RadeonHD 5650), otherwise after installing Guest Additions I could not boot into the system

---

Now we will install guest additions

> While you Virtualmachine's windows is active:
>
> Press Host+D or Devices - Install Guest Additions

```
cd /media/V {only type capital V and hit TAB it will autocomplete}
```

Now the installation

```
sudo ./VBoxLi {hit TAB here as well it will autocomplete}
```

after do this

```
sudo reboot
```

This should work. Solved my problems

Don't forget to shutdown and turn on 3d acceleration in settings

Give a message about the result

I hope it helps

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The many steps in the other solution may work. But before you do all that, you may want to try this simple little fix. I spent hours trying to solve this.

**If you you have "mouse trails" enabled for your mouse in Win 7, turn it off.**

Control Panel: Hardware: Mouse: Pointer Options Tab - Display Pointer Trails

In my case the mouse disappeared when going full screen.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server
Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop
Windows 7 64-bit

These are the conditions that produce the error for me. VirtualBox has 3D Acceleration enabled (if you uncheck it, the problem goes away but you lose 3D).

Guest Additions installed (any version from 4.2.10-4.2.18 in my case).

There is no problem if window is scaled less than full screen, but as soon as you enter Fullscreen mode (Ctrl-F) the mouse disappears.

Turning off the Display Pointer Trails in Windows fixes it.

Also used this to get the icons and the left loader bar back.

[menu bar and launcher missing in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286088/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using an external device, like a pc controller with analog sticks, then mapped the mouse directions to the right analog stick, and you could map left and right mouse click to two buttons  using a free program Joy To Key.  At least that way, when you turn off mouse integration in virtual box,  you can move the pointer around with the controller instead. It fixed the issue.