# Panel and Launcher are missing in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, launcher, panel

i have upgraded Ubuntu desktop from 12.10 to 13.04. Since then I can't see the Panel or Launcher, but I'm able to open the terminal using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T.

When I use the Guest login there is no such problem.
I am facing the problem only with administrator account. 
I have tried this [Launcher, top Panel, and window decorations missing after 12.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128676/launcher-and-window-menu-bar-missing-after-12-04-upgrade), but I couldn't find the result.

Comment: The answer you seek is on : http://askubuntu.com/q/286853/149153.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then enter:

```
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

Comment: this works, but keep in mind that it will reset the launcher!

Comment: this did not work for me. The menus appeared for a second, after the restart, then disappeared.

Comment: works when I run like that `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && unity --reset-icons &disown` at the second time.

Comment: I just login with root account in ubuntu-14.04 LTS then i can not see anything in topbar its just black panel. then i can not do anything with launcher. i have reset unity tweak tool but all try failed. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting ~/.cache or~/.gconf. Realize however that if you made any edits to the system using dconf (or gconf)-editor, they will be reset.

Another alternative is to also delete ~/.config but that would reset any and all application preferences throughout Ubuntu for your user.

See also: [Resetting Unity on 12.10 or 13.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop
```

and then reboot

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and I moved the `.config` directory and re-logged in and it is working fine for me now.

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config_old
```

I had to use the old <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal because the guest terminal wouldn't allow me to `sudo` for some reason.  Then I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to my login session.

Comment: This will erase user configuration files for A LOT of programs. Don't do it unless you are sure. I would downvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Deleting ~/.config did the trick for me.