# Top panel and launcher missing in new installation of ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, compiz, launcher

I have just installed ubuntu 13.04 on my ThinkPad laptop. I am missing the Unity launcher on the left and the Unity panel bar across the top. I only found references to the same problem for upgrades, so I tried everything written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286088/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-13-04), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286853/no-launcher-or-menu) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142772/ubuntu-12-04-upgrade-top-side-bar-missing) with no success. 
However, referring to the [second link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286853/no-launcher-or-menu), I ran `ccsm` and found my Ubuntu Unity Plugin unchecked. Checking it required to also enable the OpenGL and so I did. But, apparently I am unable to enable the OpenGL. Trying to enable it manually...and the checkbox gets automatically unchecked after few seconds.

Please help.

Update: I have Intel graphics driver, maybe the problem is specifically with it?. I also tried running `ccsm` after logging using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> like given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears). I was able to enable OpenGL and the Ubuntu Unity Plugin there, but still, no effect on my display, also after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" this by installing [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/). Just wanted to put into use an old laptop for my son so it didn't really matter to me.