# Ubuntu is in command mode how to turn on the GUI mode again?

Tags: command-line, ati, launcher, display, lightdm

I have HP Probook 4540s with Radeon graphic card, I downloaded drivers from [This site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) and installed those after reboot I couldnt see my launcher and toolbar but yes i could use few shortkeys, I looked for problem and run that
 `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` 
 `unity --reset-icons &disown`
 
 and this command 
`sudo apt-get purge fglrx lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm ubuntu-desktop`

on the terminal, [Web Link of the page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286088/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-13-04)

after running the last command i restarted and now no GUI comes up its just black command line interface and ask for my user name and password. I have no idea how to get this back to normal 
Help !

Comment: try with startx

Comment: When your sys starts try to press these keys: Ctrl+Alt+ **F2** to **F10** one by one. If you still doesn't get the GUI mode then execute this command : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. It should open a colourful screen which will prompt to select `lightdm`. Press enter and restart your system by: `sudo reboot` Reply what happens..

Comment: @SauravKumar when i enterd the command you mentioned it says `dpkg-query: package 'lightdm' is not installed and no information is available.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: lightdm is not available`
and it does nothing on alt+ctrl+f1 to f12 except on f7 it says `[  34.037654] sysRq:help:loglevel (0-9) reBoot crash terminate-all-tasks(E) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(I) the-file-system(J)......blah blah`

Comment: ha ha.. :) Now it is clear that you don't have any `display manager` installed which is causing the problem. Since you're not able to connect with internet, only thing you can do is to download .deb file of any display manager, save it to any pen drive (or any place in your system, in case of dual boot), connect it to your malfunctioned system and install it from there. So only thing I want to know that whether you're able to access any removal drive or not. For that, connect any pen drive and reply if it is able to mount in `/media`. Check it by : `ls /media`. Reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is last thing you can do to install a `display manager` to fix your problem**

- Go to following link and download **gdm**<sub>a display manager much similar to lightdm</sub> by choosing your specific Ubuntu version and architecture.

  http://pkgs.org/download/gdm
- One file with `.deb` extension will be downloaded. Save it to your pen-drive.
- Then login in `Recovery Mode`<sub>2nd option from your grub-menu</sub> when your system starts. You may have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> if your system doesn't show any `Grub Menu`. After a lot of text displayed in black screen one list will come which list some options. First go to option **Grub**, it will mount your file system in read/write mode. <sub>(Just in case go for **network** option, which will enable your network)</sub>. Then chose **root** option in order to login as root. Then go to the pendrive where you saved the deb file. The drive should be listed in in /media. I am assuming that you saved the file in `gdm` 
  directory inside `pendrive` <sub>(`pendrive` is the name of your pendrive)</sub>

  ```
  # cd /media && ls
  ```

  (which will list your `pendrive` if you don't get `pendrive`
   folder then go to **Mount Pendrive Section** at last, then come back here and continue to next step.)

  ```
  # cd /media/pendrive/gdm
  ```

  (go to gdm directory where .deb file is saved.)

  ```
  # dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

  (installing gdm)
  While installing gdm one window will come which will ask your to chose gdm
  from the list. Chose gdm. If this window doesn't appear then try following command:

  ```
  # dpkg-reconfigure gdm
  ```

  (chose gdm) Then finally execute following command:

  ```
  # reboot (reboot your system)
  ```

**Mount Pendrive Section**

- Mounting pendrive while working in recovery mode.

Run this command:

```
    # fdisk -l
```

Find your device in the list, it is probably something like `/dev/sdb1`. Then execute other commands one by another:

```
    # mkdir /media/pendrive
```

- Run this command if your pendrive is formatted in FAT/FAT32.

  ```
  # mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
  ```
- Or this command if your pendrive is formatted in NTFS

  ```
  # mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/pendrive
  ```

Hope it will work for you.. For any further assistance please reply..

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting LightDM, should work!

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Enjoy!

EDIT:
If that doesn't work try

```
sudo service lightdm start
sudo service lightdm stop
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: this doesnt work it says 

`lightdm: unrecognised service`

Comment: LightDM doesn't exist then, try reinstalling it with sudo apt-get -y install lightdm then try my answer!

Comment: well, I have only command line and I do not know how to connect to the wifi using terminal

Comment: Plug in an ethernet cable. I don't use WiFi so I do not know. Try it after this!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Ethernet cable :/ so that means I ended up in this black screen forever or I have to loose all my data ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you do not have an Ethernet cable.

Try backing up your data from a live DVD and use the Ubuntu replace option.

Comment: It seems "connect to wifi using terminal ubuntu" and similar queries yield multiple results from various StackExchange sites in Google, so I think suggesting a reinstall is pretty extreme. According to one of the comments, the OP already did a reinstall, but if we're to solve most problems this way, then this is a harsh reality we live in, heh. No year of the Linux Desktop ever ;)