# Ubuntu 13.04 no menu bar

Tags: 13.04, desktop-environments

I have lenovo thinkpad T520. Just updated to 13.04. I can see desktop icons, but no menu. I can start terminal, but I cannot close windows, move them or resize them. Also, Alt+Tab does not work. I have tried a few things, such as
[menu bar and launcher missing in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286088/menu-bar-and-launcher-missing-in-ubuntu-13-04)

but no luck. Please help, I've waisted a whole day on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you possibly take a screenshot? Do you have access to the launcher?

Comment: Does this help? [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381)