# 12.04 to 14.04: no Launcher or Panel after logout/login

Tags: unity, upgrade, launcher, panel

The solution here works for me to fix the desktop after login:  https://askubuntu.com/a/292997/227118, but I am back to square one after logging out. How to solve this issue permanently?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, courtesy of System76.com:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue, tried everything I could find on this website related to this kind of issue. Nothing helped.

What fixed it for me was re-installing the `nvidia` drivers. Weird, but it worked. I'm back in my desktop.

Something like:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-<some number>
```